# JavaScript: Double all the integers within a string

Tags: javascript, math, type-conversion

I'm trying to replace all the numbers within a string with their doubled amounts.

This was a test I was running, but it doesn't seem to be working. I also tried replacing the numbers with words and that didn't work either. What would be the best way to go about this?

```
const test = '2 TBSP Soda Pop\n 3.5 TBSP Awesome Sauce';

const regex = /\d+/g;
console.log(test.replace(regex, regex * 2));
```

Comment: `replace` accepts a callback. Do your multiplication there.

Comment: And you want to tweak your regex, I think. With `\d+`, you'll replace "3.5" with "6.10".

Comment: `console.log(test.replace(regex, (match) => match * 2));` This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution to your question:

```js
const test = '2 TBSP Soda Pop\n 3.5 TBSP Awesome Sauce';

const regex = /\d+/g;

result = test.replace(regex, function(match, contents, offset, input_string)
{
    return match*2;
});
console.log(result)
```